# hostfxr library not found when running published binary

Tags: .net-core, ubuntu-16.04

I am attempting to compile and run a standalone C# binary on Ubuntu, but I'm running into troubles with installed libraries. My understanding is that if I do a publish for a particular runtime then it should be able to run without installing the `.so` files alongside the binary, or I am making false assumptions?

When I attempt to run the application outside of its `publish` directory, I get:

> Failed to resolve library symbol hostfxr_main, error: ./neoj: undefined symbol: hostfxr_main
>   Segmentation fail (core dumped)

If I list the installed dotnet packages, it currently looks like this:

> dotnet-host/xenial,now 2.0.0-preview2-25407-01-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
>   dotnet-hostfxr-2.0.0/xenial,now 2.0.0-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
>   dotnet-runtime-2.0.0/xenial,now 2.0.0-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
>   dotnet-sdk-2.0.2/xenial,now 2.0.2-1 amd64 [installed]

There seem to be a few discrepancies, but those are the dependencies pulled into automatically if I install the SDK.

If I use `ldconfig -p | grep libhostfxr` to check for the library then, predictably, it returns no results. I tried added `/usr/share/dotnet/` in a config file, adding a symlink in that directory to the `.so` file and updating the cache (`sudo ldconfig`) which results in the library being added to the cache, but still no joy when attempting to run the command.

I've attempted to resolve this by updating the runtime framework version to 2.0.0 which resulted in a slightly more friendly error message, but the same result.

Source files are [all here](https://github.com/chooban/neo-compiler) in case it's something non-obvious!